# Moving entities between contexts in .NET Entity Framework 3.5

Tags: entity-framework

I've got a scenario in which I want to move a bunch of object graphs
between contexts.  Specifically, I'm trying to import the contents of
one database into another.  The there is a context [CurrentContext]
connected to the primary DB, and another context [ImportContext]
connected to another DB.  I'd like to copy the entities from
ImportContext into CurrentContext, either inserting new records or
updating the existing records.
Something like this.

ImportContext.Organization.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
foreach(var org in ImportContext.Organizations.ToList())
{
CurrentContext.Attach(org); // or
CurrentContext.AddToOrganization(org);
}

When I try the Attach method, the entity isn't saved because the
entitystate is Unchanged, and I can't figure out how to mark it as
new. Also, it appears Attach doesn't work if the entity is new,
because the EntityKey is tied to ImportContext.
If I set the EntityKey to null, I lose the associations between the
Organization and other entities.
AddToOrganization has the same problem with losing the associations,
or would fail if the Organization was once already in the
CurrentContext.

What's the appropriate approach to doing this type of importing?  I'm
currently using EF3.5 and can't update the project to EF4.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Detach` the entity from the old context.
2. `AddObject` the entity into the new context.

Comment: That doesn't work, in some cases the entity is not new, it's just updated.  Also, when I detach the entity, I lose the rest of the object graph, which also needs to be either added or updated.

Comment: You need to be more specific.

Comment: There is a Context [C1] that contains items A,B,C, q,x,y,z and another Context [C2] with C, D, E, x,y,z.  A has a collection with items q,x,y; [C1].C has a collection with items x,y,z; [C2].C has a collection with items x,y.
I'd like to copy the items in [C1] (A,B,C,q,x,y,z) into [C2].  If the item doesn't exist in [C2], I want it to be added, if it does exist, I want it to be updated.

Comment: There is no one-step "upsert" feature. You would need to select from [C2], and update if it's there, add if it's not.

Comment: Ok, but how do I handle the relationships? When I detach the object from the context, the relationships are removed as well.

Comment: What I would probably do in that case is to select the entity without change tracking in the first place. So set the `query.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking`. Now the entity won't be in the context to begin with.